# Number of Pythagorean triples between $10<a+b-c<18$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, integers, pythagorean-triples

A competition problem asks:

How many Pythagorean triples $(a,b,c)$ ($c$ being the hypotenuse) exist such that:

$$10<a+b-c<18?$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $gcd(a,b,c)=1$ and $a$ be an even natural number.

Thus, there are naturals $m$ and $n$ with different parity such that $m>n$, $gcd(m,n)=1$ for which $a=2mn$, $b=m^2-n^2$ and $c=m^2+n^2$.

Thus,

$$10<2mn+m^2-n^2-m^2-n^2<12$$ or
$$5<n(m-n)<9$$ or
$$6\leq n(m-n)\leq8$$ and the rest is a finite number of cases and systems.

After all this we need to check $d(a,b,c)$, where $d=gcd(a,b,c)$

and we remember that we can change $a$ with $b$.

Comment: @Arthur Yes of course. Thank you!

Comment: This only counts primitive triples, though. If you relax $\gcd(m,n)=1$ you get some of them, but not all. I'm uncertain as to whether the non-primitive ones should be counted.

Comment: @Arthur It was hint only. After all this we need to check $d(a,b,c)$ of course. Also we can change $a$ which $b$.

Comment: Yes, that's another thing. Does $(18,24,30)$ count as the same as $(24,18,30)$, or as a different one? Anywho, I know you're allowed to give non-complete answers. I just think it's important to point it out when you do.

Comment: @Arthur See please my previous comment.

Comment: @Michael Rozenberg ; thank you for your fruitful ideas.